# Opening website through chrome open command

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, startup, kiosk

I need to, on computer startup, open chrome on --kiosk mode into a specific site. I already have a command on startup apps to boot Chrome into kiosk, but it won't load the default page I set in the desktop version.

```
Google-chrome --kiosk
```

Is there a parameter I could add to the startup command to open a specific URL?

Please mind that this is my first time dealing with Linux (Been working with Windows all my life though)

Comment: UbuntuMATE 18.04. I think I almost got it working, but the command opening on startup happens BEFORE the Wifi connects, so it fails

Comment: Have you tried the answers from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18702214/9152951.
For me the command "google-chrome --kiosk www.example.com" works

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just missing quotes on "URL"
The functioning command is:

```
Google-chrome --kiosk "URL"
```

ALSO, if there is a previous chrome tab opened before, this won't work (or likely opens a second tab but doesnt switch to view that one)

Thanks to everyone who dropped by.